# Spring-security-cas plugin Single Sign Out not working

Tags: grails, spring-security, logout, cas, spring-security-cas

I'm very new to grails and I'm developing an app with Spring-Security-Core and Spring-Security-CAS plugins.

The single sign on is working as expected, but I'm in trouble with the single sign out.

I have two applications, and when I log in in cas or in anyone of the apps, I can access the 2 applications without any problems. But when I try to logout using app1/logout or app2/logout only the cas and the application session that is calling the /logout are closed and I'm still able to navigate though the other app.

example:
log app1 through cas login 
log app2 through cas ticket validation
logout from app1 -> app1 and cas session are closed but app2 is still logged in (it should be logged out here)

Anyone has an idea on how to fix it?

---

### UPDATING

when I'm logged in my two apps and try to logout from one, I can sees these posts calls in localhost_access_log.txt:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Apr/2014:14:36:05 -0300] "GET /app/logout/index HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Apr/2014:14:36:05 -0300] "GET /app/j_spring_security_logout HTTP/1.1" 302 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Apr/2014:14:36:05 -0300] "GET /cas/logout?service=http://localhost:8090/app/logout/afterLogout HTTP/1.1" 200 2039
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Apr/2014:14:36:05 -0300] "POST /app2/j_spring_cas_security_check HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Apr/2014:14:36:05 -0300] "POST /app/j_spring_cas_security_check HTTP/1.1" 200 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Apr/2014:14:36:05 -0300] "GET /cas/images/confirm.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 958
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Apr/2014:14:36:05 -0300] "GET /cas/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 170
```

I believe that it should be enough to logout from my two apps but app2 isnt logging out, only app1 (app)

any advice would be welcome =D

thanks

Comment: I use CAS but not via a plugin - through a custom library. We had a similar issue and had to redirect our logout calls via a controller in our app which did: `session.invalidate()` and `redirect(url:"${params.casUrl}?url=${params.appUrl}")`. Invalidating the session was the key. Maybe the plugin has an option to do this for you?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already set `afterLogoutUrl` parameter? It manages cas logout after corresponding logout from grails.

Here is an example taken from one of my applications:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.logout.afterLogoutUrl = "https://$servercas/cas/logout?url=http://$servercas/mygrailsapp/"
```

For details see [CAS plugin docs](http://burtbeckwith.github.io/grails-spring-security-cas/docs/manual/guide/2.%20Usage.html) under *Single Sign Out*

Comment: Thanks, it helps me to find a typo error in afterLogoutUrl

Comment: Is the afterLogoutUrl necessary for single logout to work? I have them setup in both applications but having the same trouble as the original poster.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's an obscure feature in spring-security-core Grails plugin that conflicts with Single sign-out, as implemented in the CAS Java client.

This is documented in a [bug from Jan 2011](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-1658) which apparently nobody is interested in solving.

There is a simple workaround, just disable the obscure feature in your Config:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.seSessionFixationPrevention = false
```